# Updating property of object in array in NGRX/Redux store not working

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, redux, ngrx

In my Reducer, I'm trying to update the property of an object in an array held within a dictionary collection, but it's not working and I can't figure out why. The results property of my state is a dictionary of key/value pairs, and the value is an array.

I tried to use the map function to create a new array but my results and state does not update. This is my code:

```
 case LOAD_SUCCESS: {
      const form = (action as LoadSuccessAction).form;

      return {
         results: {
           ...state.results,
           ...state.results['FORMS'].map(item => 
             item.id === form .id
              ? {...item, 'categories': form.categories}
              : item)           
         },    
        loading: false,
        loaded: true
      };
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here:

```typescript
...state.results['FORMS'].map(…),
```

you’re merging the *array* of updated items (updated `FORMS`) with state’s `results` property (the *object* containing `FORMS`).

If item’s categories and ids were numbers, the end result would look like this (only showing `results`):

```typescript
{
    '0': { categories: 15, id: 10 },
    '1': { categories: 7, id: 11 },
    FORMS: [ /* its original content before the update */ ],
}
```

Instead, you should set new state’s `FORMS` property to your updated array:

```typescript
return {
    // loaded, loading…
    results: {
        ...state.results,
        FORMS: state.results.FORMS.map(
            item => item.id === form.id ? {
                ...item,
                categories: form.categories,
            } : item,
        ),
    },
}
```